# Add a row above row headers in R

Tags: r

I want to add an extra row above what is row 1 of the following dataframe (i.e. above the labels a, b and Percent):

```
a<-c(1:5) 
b<-c(4,3,2,1,1) 
Percent<-c(40,30,20,10,10)  
df1<-data.frame(a,b,Percent)
```

These dataframes represent questions in an interview analysis I am doing, and I want to include the question descriptor above the row headers so I can easily identify which dataframe belongs to which question (i.e. "Age"). I have been using rbind to add rows, but is it possible to use this command above the row headers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is just meta-data, you can add it as an attribute to the data.frame.

```
> attr(df1, "Question") <- "Age"
> attributes(df1)
$names
[1] "a"       "b"       "Percent"
$row.names
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
$class
[1] "data.frame"
$Question
[1] "Age"
```

If you want the question to be printed above the data.frame, 
you can define a `Question` class, that extends `data.frame`,
and override the `print` method.

```
class(df1) <- c( "Question", class(df1) )
print.Question <- function( x, ... ) {
  if( ! is.null( attr(x, "Question") ) ) {
    cat("Question:", attr(x, "Question"), "\n")
  }
  print.data.frame(x)
}
df1
```

But that looks overkill: it may be simpler to just add a column.

```
> df1$Question <- "Age"
> df1
  a b Percent Question
1 1 4      40      Age
2 2 3      30      Age
3 3 2      20      Age
4 4 1      10      Age
5 5 1      10      Age
```

Comment: Thanks @Vincent Zoonekynd, however is it possible that "Age" can be added as the very first row (above the a, b and Percent) and not as a column?  Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain how to display the attribute by default. But it is meta-data, not data: for instance, if you save the data.frame to a CSV file, that will disappear -- that is why I prefer to add a column, even if it is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

`rbind` is really the only way to go but everything would switch to atomic data. For example:

```
cols <- c("Age", "Age", "Age")
df1 <- rbind(cols,df1)
str(df1)
```

Definitely agree with Vincent on this one, I do this quite frequently with survey data, if it's all in one data.frame I generally set a `comment` attribute on each element of the data.frame(), it's also useful when you perform multiple operations and you want to maintain reasonable `colnames(df1)`. It's not good practice, but if this is for presentation you can always set `check.names=F` when you create your `data.frame()`

```
a<-c(1:5) 
b<-c(4,3,2,1,1) 
Percent<-c(40,30,20,10,10)  
df1<-data.frame(a,b,Percent)

comment(df1$a) <- "Q1a. This is a likert scale"
comment(df1$b) <- "Q1b. This is another likert scale"
comment(df1$Percent) <- "QPercent. This is some other question"
```

Then, if I "forget" what's in the columns, I can take a quick peak:

```
sapply(df1, comment)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish this was a part of core R, but I hacked up a solution with [Jason Bryer's Likert package](https://github.com/jbryer/likert) using attributes to store column names, and having the likert function read these attributes and use them when plotting. It only works with that function though - there a function HMisc called label, but again none of the functions care about this (including the functions that show dataframes etc).

Here's a writeup of my hack http://reganmian.net/blog/2013/10/02/likert-graphs-in-r-embedding-metadata-for-easier-plotting/, with a link to the code.